# Lucene TFIDF does not return 1 for exactly same query with certain document

Tags: lucene, tf-idf

I implemented a program to rank documents based on its TFIDF similarity score given a user input.

Following is the program:

```
public class Ranking{

    private static int maxHits = 10;
    private static Connection connect = null;
    private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    private static ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {        
        System.out.println("Enter your paper title: ");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String paperTitle = null;
        paperTitle = br.readLine(); 

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/arnetminer?"
                  + "user=root&password=1234");
        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement
        ("SELECT stoppedstemmedtitle from arnetminer.new_bigdataset "
                + "where title="+"'"+paperTitle+"';");
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        resultSet.next();
        String stoppedstemmedtitle = resultSet.getString(1);

        String querystr = args.length > 0 ? args[0] :stoppedstemmedtitle;
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42);
        Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_42, "stoppedstemmedtitle", analyzer).parse(querystr);

        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File("E:/Lucene/new_bigdataset_index")));        
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        VSMSimilarity vsmSimiliarty = new VSMSimilarity();  
        searcher.setSimilarity(vsmSimiliarty);
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(q, maxHits);
        ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = hits.scoreDocs;

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("E:/Lucene/result/1.txt", "UTF-8");

        int counter = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < scoreDocs.length; ++n) {
            ScoreDoc sd = scoreDocs[n];
            System.out.println(scoreDocs[n]);
            float score = sd.score;
            int docId = sd.doc;
            Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
            String fileName = d.get("title");
            String year = d.get("pub_year");
            String paperkey = d.get("paperkey");
            System.out.printf("%s,%s,%s,%4.3f\n", paperkey, fileName, year, score);
            writer.printf("%s,%s,%s,%4.3f\n", paperkey, fileName, year, score);
        ++counter;
        }
        writer.close();

    }


}
```

And

```
public class VSMSimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity{

    // Weighting codes
    public boolean doBasic     = true;  // Basic tf-idf
    public boolean doSublinear = false; // Sublinear tf-idf
    public boolean doBoolean   = false; // Boolean

    //Scoring codes
    public boolean doCosine    = true;
    public boolean doOverlap   = false;

    // term frequency in document = measure of how often a term appears in the document
    public float tf(int freq) {     

        return super.tf(freq);
    }

    // inverse document frequency = measure of how often the term appears across the index
    public float idf(int docFreq, int numDocs) {

        // The default behaviour of Lucene is 1 + log (numDocs/(docFreq+1)), which is what we want (default VSM model)
        return super.idf(docFreq, numDocs); 
    }

    // normalization factor so that queries can be compared 
    public float queryNorm(float sumOfSquaredWeights){

        return super.queryNorm(sumOfSquaredWeights);
    }

    // number of terms in the query that were found in the document
    public float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {

        // else: can't get here
        return super.coord(overlap, maxOverlap);
    }

    // Note: this happens an index time, which we don't take advantage of (too many indices!)
    public float computeNorm(String fieldName, FieldInvertState state){

        // else: can't get here
        return super.computeNorm(state);
    }
}
```

However, it does not return value 1 for exact documents that has 100% similarity with the input.

If i put user input as follows:`Logic Based Knowledge Representation`
The output I got and the TFIDF score are (5.165 for document that has 100% similarity with the input):

```
3086,Logic Based Knowledge Representation.,1999,5.165
33586,A Logic for the Representation of Spatial Knowledge.,1991,4.663
328937,Logic Programming for Knowledge Representation.,2007,4.663
219720,Logic for Knowledge Representation.,1984,4.663
487587,Knowledge Representation with Logic Programs.,1997,4.663
806195,Logic Programming as a Representation of Knowledge.,1983,4.663
806833,The Role of Logic in Knowledge Representation.,1983,4.663
744914,Knowledge Representation and Logic Programming.,2002,4.663
1113802,Knowledge Representation in Fuzzy Logic.,1989,4.663
984276,Logic Programming and Knowledge Representation.,1994,4.663
```

Is this a normal thing or is there something wrong with my tfidf implementation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: why it should return 1?

Comment: @Mysterion Am I wrong because according to my understanding so far I think that document with 100% similarity has to return 1? Correct me if im wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - Lucene already have TF-IDF similarity - *org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.TFIDFSimilarity*

Second one -

> tf–idf, short for term frequency–inverse document frequency, is a
>   numerical statistic that is intended to reflect how important a **word**
>   is to a document in a collection or corpus

I've marked word, so this tf-idf stuff is applicable only for one word query, but when query have mutliple words tf-idf will be done like this:

> One of the simplest ranking functions is computed by summing the
>   tf–idf for each query term

So, this is the reason, why tf-idf could return you a score more than 1

Comment: Thanks so much Im starting to understand. I wanna ask one question though. I noticed that Lucene has TFIDFSimilarity class. But if I extend the DefaultSimilarity instead, it will produce the same results is that correct? Because from all I know DefaultSimilarity extends the TFIDFSimilarity class. Im just afraid there is some problem in this program since im not using TFIDFSimilarity class